# MsTest Fails in CMD when using relative path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmd, mstest

I have a folder that contains all the files needed by tests.

```
testResources
    testRes.txt
```

In my test I have a relativ path to testResources defined in a `const`

`private const string testRes = @"..\..\..\testResources\testRes.txt";`

The test that depends on testResources **passes**, when using visual studio, however when the same test is run by `MsTest` in command line the tests **FAILS**, casting file not found exception.

How is that possible and how to fix this`?

**More Info:**

The output path is set to: `bin\Debug\`

MsTest running path differ from Visual studio path.
I dont have control over MsTest path.

language: C# .net 4.0

Comment: Could you try using absolute paths instead of relative paths? It could be that MSTest is running from where it lives, and not from current directory (this is just a thought tho)

Comment: Yes, MSTest path differ, but i dont have the control over MSTest path :(

Comment: If it's a different path, than you for sure are not going to get it to work as is.  We have a build server that runs into a similar issue, I just test if the original path exists, if not, move to a secondary path (which you should be able to figure out based on the MsTest path).